# What is the equivalent of h(t)=0 Matlab expression in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I am translating a MATLAB code to Python code but I couldn't understand what `h(t) = 0` means. What is the equivalent in Python?

Where `h` and `t` is `(494,475,3)` array:

```
t = sum((h.^2+v.^2),3)<lambda/beta;
t = repmat(t,[1,1,D]);
h(t) = 0; v(t) = 0;
```

Comment: Check: [Matrix indexing in matlab](https://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Comment: what is the equivalent in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is a MATLAB matrix with elements that are either true or false.
`h(t)` gives all elements of `h` where the corresponding elements in `t` are true.
These are set to 0 with `h(t) = 0`

You can do the same in Python.

```
h[t] = 0
```

where `h` and `t` are numpy arrays.